# When referring to kilometers, what is the equivalent of "mileage"?

Tags: word-usage

When describing how far a car can drive, you might say:

> This car has a *mileage* of 12,000 miles a year.

When dealing with metric units of kilometers, is it still appropriate to refer to *mileage*?

> This car has a *mileage* of 20,000 kilometers a year.

---

A related usage is when referring to a road sign that displays how far away a city is. For example, a road sign that says:

> New York - 23

would be understood to be a *mileage sign* that indicates that New York is 23 miles away. A similar sign in Canada might read:

> Vancouver - 37

which would indicate that Vancouver is 37 kilometers away. Is it still appropriate to refer to this sign as a *mileage sign* even though we're using kilometers?

---

I'm seeing some speculation online that "kilometerage" or "kilometrage" might be a word used here, but they sound off to me. "kilométrage" seems to be the appropriate word in French. What should be used in English?

Comment: "Mileage" refers to the distance on a vehicle, regardless of the unit of meausre

Answer (score 2):

There is no good equivalent for mileage. As you said kilometrage looks and sounds awkward. I heard it once or twice after decimal conversion, but not more recently. You would be better to use range or distance depending on context.

Answer (score -3):

Umm, I don't know what "this car has a mileage of 12000miles per years" would even mean. Mileage to me means how far you can go on a given amount of fuel (miles per gallon, kilometers per liter) and for that usage I suggest "fuel economy", it's not as convenient as "mileage" but does have the same meaning (even better it can be used regardless of whether the current locale uses miles or kilometers).

Comment: In my example, mileage isn't referring to fuel economy, but rather the dictionary definition of "number of miles traveled or covered", giving the original sentence the roughly equivalent meaning of "This car has traveled 12,000 miles per year". Your example is good when referring specifically to fuel economy though!

Comment: Okay, if you change it to "I drive 20000 miles a year for my job" I have encountered that being called mileage, I have simply never encountered that formulation being applied to a particular vehicle (any modern car had better be able to do far more than 20k miles a year). And for that use I'm not sure there is a useful substitute. Certainly if the job reimburses travel that could apply regardless of miles or kilometers ("My job reimburses up to 25000 kilometers a year at X.15/km" with X being the applicable currency unit).